# Google Map loading partially on click on the hidden tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using 2 tabs, first for showing list and another showing map.
When the first time page is loaded 1 tab is shown by default and on click of second tab map is shown, but when i click list tab and again click map tab map loading partially.

Here is my JAVASCRIPT code:

```
$(document).on('click', "#load-map-view", function() {
        locateStores();
        $("#store-list-view").hide();
        $("#store-list-view").removeClass('disabled');

        $("#store-map-view").show();
        $("#store-map-view").addClass('disabled');
    });

function locateStores() {
    var mapContent;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("store-map-view"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 13
    });
    var markers = [];
    $("#store-list-view .listed-shop").each(function() {
        markers.push({
            lat: $(this).attr('data-lat'),
            lng: $(this).attr('data-lan'),
            name: $.trim($(this).find('div.shop-name').text())
        });
    });
for (index in markers)
        addMarker(markers[index]);
    function addMarker(data) {


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
            map: map,
            title: data.name
        });

        var infobox = new InfoBox({
            content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 150,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -10),
            zIndex: null,
            boxStyle: {
                background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
                opacity: 0.80,
                width: "400px"//"280px"
            },
            closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        });

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setZoom(map.getZoom());

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            $(".infoBox").fadeOut(300);
            infobox.open(map, this);
            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418));
        });
    }

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (index in markers) {
        var data = markers[index];
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

var pin = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    function openInfoWindow(marker) {
        title.innerHTML = marker.getTitle();
        pin.set("position", marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

I have tried several solutions like :
adding this code

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

and many other solutions, but still the page still isn't loading.

can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the problem I was getting.

I was adding below code on wrong position:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

The solution to my problem is:

If you are using map for hidden div. Declare map variable as global.

Then show the div first, load the map after div is shown and resize it using the code given.

```
    var map; //globalize your map variable
            // Then do the necessary loading

    $(document).on('click', "#load-map-view", function() {
            $("#store-list-view").hide();
            $("#store-list-view").removeClass('disabled');

            locateStores();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    $("#store-map-view").show();
            $("#store-map-view").addClass('disabled');
        });
```